# Quanto si usa la parola purché

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

Prima di sapere il significato,  non lo notavo nelle conversazioni, cioè,  o si pronuncia molto simile a perché o si utilizza molto poco,  ha anche un sinonimo? O si usa poco?

Comment: Nel [Dizionario De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/purche), il vocabolo "purché" appare con la marca d'uso "[AU](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6)", cioè, "di alto uso; sono così marcati i vocaboli di alta frequenza, le cui occorrenze costituiscono un altro 6% circa delle occorrenze lessicali nell’insieme di tutti i testi scritti o discorsi parlati". Quindi, non si tratta di un vocabolo di altissima frequenza (quelli sono marcati con "FO"), ma non è neanche raro.

Answer (score 1):

Purché è, almeno nella conversazione, poco utilizzato.
È difficile confonderlo con "perché", sopratutto perché sono di significato molto diverso: "perché", infatti, introduce una frase causale o finale, mentre purché indica una condizione, come nella frase: "Mangerò molto volentieri la carne, purché non sia troppo al sangue". Nella conversazione, però, si preferisce usare "a patto che", "sempre che" o simili locuzioni seguite dal congiuntivo.

Comment: A me personalmente “purché” non suona più ricercato delle altre locuzioni che menzioni. Per pura curiosità, visto che si riferisce solo a testi scritti, ecco la frequenza rispettiva delle tre espressioni [su Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purch%C3%A9%2Ca+patto+che%2Csempre+che&year_start=1800&year_end=2100&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurch%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20patto%20che%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csempre%20che%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: *Purché* vuole il congiuntivo, a differenza di *perché* che vuole l'indicativo. Non vedo questa facilità di confusione. Personalmente adopero *purché* senza problemi.